# copy range of cells from a spreadsheet and paste into a form edit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google form set up for an accident report. I currently have a google spreadsheet with all of the employee names. I can manually copy the range of cells that house the employee names, go to edit form, edit the **"choose from a list"** > **"Name"** question that is on the form. I then click my cursor into the 1st list box and paste. It then fills out the form list with the most current employee list. Is there a way to create a script that does this? It would hopefully be triggered by any change in the range of cells (i.e. an employee being added or deleted).

So the step by step process would be:

- Select "Employee" spreadsheet.
- Select and Copy Range "A2:B100"
- Go to 'Form'- 'Edit Form'
- Edit "Name" question
- Insert cursor into list box 1 and paste
- Select Done
- Close Form

I have zero script programming knowledge. I can edit a pre-existing script okay, but to write one from scratch is beyond my knowledge base.

Answer (score 0):

Your outline of the process steps is an excellent place to start and Apps Script is a great environment to learn how to script. (brand new to me <6 months ago).

Each of those steps should have very good documentation at [spreadsheet apps script service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/).

Post your first attempt at the code and we can go from there.

Sorry for the Socrates answers, but when possible "Teach a man to fish"!

Jacob

Answer (score -1):

No need for a script to do this. You can use the google add-ons: "formRanger". 
& set its update options (Auto-repopulate questions) to:
On form submit: ON

### Every hour: ON

Enjoy!!!

Comment: You should add more context, and a better explanation of what you're doing.  It's not obvious at all that you're talking about spreadsheets here.